# Where to learn about parabolic Hölder spaces and when to use them

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Is there a good resource from where I can learn about *parabolic Hölder spaces*? I see quite a few different definitions of this space in different papers. I am clueless about why, for example, one may want your initial condition (or solution) to some PDE to be in the space $C^{k+2, \alpha}$. This is more restrictive than the space $C^{k+2}$ and I don't know what the payoff is.

How do I know which function spaces to use?

Comment: Considering how much of PDE theory concerns finding suitable function spaces to use for a given equation, I doubt that there's any easy answer to "how do I know which function spaces to use" besides (a) experience (someone else used it and it worked) and (b) extreme cleverness (sadly, nothing that I am qualified to explain), plus a small dose of scaling considerations. 

Comment: One simple reason why you get a payoff is the following "gain of derivatives" (let's consider the elliptic case, the parabolic case is similar): if $\Delta u=f$ in some domain and $f\in C^k$ it does not follow that $u\in C^{k+2}_{loc}$. However, if $f\in C^{k,\alpha}$ and $0<\alpha<1$, then it does follow that $u\in C^{k+2,\alpha}_{loc}$ by Schauder estimates.

Comment: A widely used reference for parabolic PDE is Friedman's "PDE of Parabolic Type" which might be of some help. http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=181836

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'll look for that book in the library.

Comment: @quentinknight a more recent book on Holder space theory in PDE is N. V. Krylov - Lectures on Elliptic and Parabolic Equations in Hölder Spaces http://books.google.com/books?id=CMYFT6oo7-wC&printsec=frontcover&hl=ru&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. Very useful since my library doesn't stock Friedman unfortunately..

Answer (score 3):

The book by N. Krylov is a great reference, but there are some other references that may help with understanding:

- *Krylov, N. V.*, Lectures on elliptic and parabolic equations in Sobolev spaces, Graduate Studies in Mathematics 96. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 978-0-8218-4684-1/hbk). xviii, 357 p. (2008). [ZBL1147.35001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1147.35001).
- *Behrndt, T.*  Generalized Lagrangian Mean Curvature Flow in Almost Calabi-Yau Manifolds, doctoral thesis. PDF [link](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/joyce/theses/BehrndtDPhil.pdf).
- *Griepentrog, Jens André; Recke, Lutz*, [**Local existence, uniqueness and smooth dependence for nonsmooth quasilinear parabolic problems**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00028-010-0052-4), J. Evol. Equ. 10, No. 2, 341-375 (2010). [ZBL1239.35084](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1239.35084).
- *Ibrahim, Hassan*, [**A generalization of a logarithmic Sobolev inequality to the Hölder class**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1155/2012/148706), J. Funct. Spaces Appl. 2012, Article ID 148706, 15 p. (2012). [ZBL1242.46041](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1242.46041).
- *Schlag, Wilhelm*, [**Schauder and $L^ p$ estimates for parabolic systems via Campanato spaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/03605309608821221), Commun. Partial Differ. Equations 21, No. 7-8, 1141-1175 (1996). [ZBL0864.35023](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0864.35023). Link on author's website [here](https://gauss.math.yale.edu/%7Ews442/papers/SCHAU.pdf).