# Reference/proof for parabolic Holder spaces property

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Suppose that a function $u:[0,1]\times[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}$ belongs to the parabolic Holder space $C^{2+\alpha,1+\alpha/2}$, for $\alpha\in(0,1)$.

What can be said about $u_x=\partial_x u$?

I am not an expert, I was told that it actually should belong to $C^{1+\alpha,1/2+\alpha/2}$ (unfortunately without any reference).

Does anyone know a good reference (or a proof) for this fact (if true - or at least if $u$ is a solution of a some parabolic equation)? Or an easy way to see that at least $u_x$ is continuous.

Analogously, if $u\in C^{2n+\alpha,n+\alpha/2}$ then $u_x$ should be in $C^{2n-1+\alpha,n-1/2+\alpha/2}$.

Thanks, c

Comment: Maybe the references in the question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100690/where-to-learn-about-parabolic-h%C3%B6lder-spaces-and-when-to-use-them) help.

Comment: Thanks. In Krylov book mentioned there such property is given as an exercise. I am going for a crash course in parabolic Holder spaces...